# Error when executing PowerShell on target machines using PSSession

Tags: azure, powershell, permissions, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, winrm

I am executing a powershell script on a target machine using Azure DevOps release pipeline (which uses PSSession) and I have got the following error:

```
2022-06-17T12:27:22.1621620Z ##[section]Starting: PowerShell Script - Backup Temp DB
2022-06-17T12:27:22.2530275Z ==============================================================================
2022-06-17T12:27:22.2530704Z Task         : PowerShell on target machines
2022-06-17T12:27:22.2531137Z Description  : Execute PowerShell scripts on remote machines using PSSession and Invoke-Command for remoting
2022-06-17T12:27:22.2531501Z Version      : 3.200.0
2022-06-17T12:27:22.2531752Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
2022-06-17T12:27:22.2532172Z Help         : https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/powershell-on-target-machines
2022-06-17T12:27:22.2532638Z ==============================================================================
2022-06-17T12:29:58.1951592Z ##[error]Unable to create pssession. Error: 'Connecting to remote server NewDBServer.XYZ.local failed with the following error message : WinRM cannot complete the operation. Verify that the specified computer name is valid, that the computer is accessible over the network, and that a firewall exception for the WinRM service is enabled and allows access from this computer. By default, the WinRM firewall exception for public profiles limits access to remote computers within the same local subnet. For more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.'
2022-06-17T12:30:19.4281448Z ##[error]The remote session query failed for NewDBServer.XYZ.local with the following error message: WinRM cannot complete the operation. Verify that the specified computer name is valid, that the computer is accessible over the network, and that a firewall exception for the WinRM service is enabled and allows access from this computer. By default, the WinRM firewall exception for public profiles limits access to remote computers within the same local subnet. 
2022-06-17T12:30:19.4694522Z ##[error]PSSession could not be created for Machine:'NewDBServer.XYZ.local:5986'
2022-06-17T12:30:19.5266279Z ##[section]Finishing: PowerShell Script - Backup Temp DB
```

what am I missing here?

**Update 1:**

I logged into the NewDBServer using the credentials that I mentioned in the DevOps and task. This is what I got:

[image]

Comment: Is the WinRM service running on the remote computer? This article might help: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_remote_troubleshooting?view=powershell-7.2

Comment: @LightningWar It is working since I was able to run the PSSession via a Super admin... Here I have created a new local admin this purpose

Answer (score 1):

Don't know how helpful it will be however I sent the protocol to HTTP instead of HTTPS. So port 5985 was used and there were no issues.